# Pass parameter to button click to another button click-Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons **VIEW JOB** and **APPLY JOB** . When I click **VIEW JOB** a modal window appear and contain a button **APPLY**. When I click the **APPLY** button in modal the click event of **APPLY JOB** will called.

```
<button id="view_job">VIEW JOB</button>
<button id="apply_job">APPLY JOB</button>
```

button in modal window

```
<button id="apply_job2">APPLY</button>

$("#apply_job").click(function(){
var jobid=$(this).parent().find(".job").val();
//manage parameter from popup button click
//common code..
});
$("#apply_job2").click(function(){
  $(".jobpanel").parent().find("#apply_job").click(); //here need to pass parameter
});
```

So when I click both apply job button(in page and in popup) same action is occured (action of apply_job button). But I have to distinguish that from where the action occured. That is, if from popup, I need to do some extra things..So can I pass some parameteres to the button click from popup.

Comment: Yes you can. Please click `<>` and give us a [mcve] so we can tell you how

Comment: Without seeing the code, You could do `$("#apply_job2").click(function(){
  someParameter="someValue";
  $(".jobpanel").parent().find("#apply_job").click();
});` and have `$("#apply_job").click(function(){ doSomething(someParameter)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your problem, you can do with html data attribute:

```
$("#apply_job").click(function(){
var jobid=$(this).parent().find(".job").val();

 //check if you have added the parameter
 var parameterValue=$(this).attr('data-PARAMETER_NAME');

 if(parameterValue){
   //do something
 }else{
   //do something else
 }
});
$("#apply_job2").click(function(){
  $(".jobpanel").parent().find("#apply_job").attr("data-PARAMETER_NAME","PARAMETER");
  $(".jobpanel").parent().find("#apply_job").click(); 

  //remove atribute here
  $(".jobpanel").parent().find("#apply_job").attr("data-PARAMETER_NAME","");
});
```